# How to get sum value in a column from same roll and show all row using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've a `ams_marks` table. I want to get `sum` value in a column from same roll and show all records with sum. I was try `$this->db->group_by()` method but it show only single row under a roll. But I want to show all row with `roll` sum result in a `Obtain Mark` column using `Position` column. How can I solve it by `CodeIgniter` ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ams_marks am
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT SUM(obtain_mark) as position,roll FROM ams_marks am_g 
          GROUP BY roll
        ) as ams_sum on ams_sum.roll = am.roll";

$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

It will populate the position field with the SUM of obtain mark.